# 74LVC inverter gate power consumption

Tags: logic-gates, power-consumption

I am using a microcontroller to drive a flyback transformer. The driving circuit contain speedup capacitor as shown in the figure, as to protect the microcontroller from relatively high currents generated by the speedup capacitor I have added a 74LVC1G14 inverter in between to be used as a buffer. 
The problem is the inverter draws more current than expected. It draws about 2.5mA though the load draws 0.5mA only. I know that when the CMOS change its state there is a short circuit between Vcc and GND for short time when the two MOSFETs are On, but with my 100KHz frequency I think this 2.5mA is too much. 
[image]
Any one know what is the problem with this inverter circuit? 
Did I make something wrong?

Comment: The speed up cap which is a good idea for your BC807 BJT  does increase the current draw.Considre a smaller cap or lower frequency or ever a small P chan mosfet.

Comment: let say if i used BSS84P PMOS, I will not need the speed-up capacitor right? In that case I will not need the inverter too because the currents will not be that much for the microcontroller

Comment: Yes the little p channel is your friend .It does not need speed up capacitance.Its effective capacitance including miller effect is much less than the sped up BJT.

Comment: Ok that is great, But for confirmation again, Does the speed-up capacitor is the one responsible of that 2.5mA drawn by the inverter or its the short circuit made by inverter CMOS in transition?

Comment: What voltage is VCC?

Comment: the Vcc voltage is 5 volt

Comment: With such a high-capacitance load and a frequency that high above DC the totem pole output is essentially *always* in a short circuit through the load.

Comment: what is the totem pole output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 5.6K/820Ω divider is dropping the BC807's Base voltage to about 630mV, barely enough to turn it on. Your 'speed up' capacitor is doing more than just speeding up the BC807's switching speed - it is actually providing most of the Base drive current.

The 74LVC1G14 is drawing 'high' current because it has to continuously charge and discharge this large 'speed up' capacitor.

To reduce inverter current draw you should increase the 820Ω resistor to a much higher value (eg. 4k7) so the transistor gets sufficient drive through RB, and reduce the value of the 'speed up' capacitor until it is just sufficient to maintain a fast switching speed (eg. 100pF).

Comment: Ok that is great, I will do it, thanks a lot.  I may also just use PMOS and reduce the current and components counts.
Thanks again